# How to get output layer values during training tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

Is it possible to get the output layer values during the training in order to build a custom loss function. 
to be more specific i want to get the output value and compute the loss using external method
my problem is I can't pass `tf.eval()` before initialize variables using `tf.global_variables_initializer()`

```
def run_command(im_path,p):
    s = 'cmd'+p.eval()
    os.system(s)
    im = imread(im_path)
    return im
def cross_corr(y_true, y_pred):
    path1 = 'path_to_input_image'
    true_image = run_command(path1, y_pred)
    path2 = 'path_to_predicted_image'
    predicted_image = run_command(path2,y_true)
    pearson_r, update_op = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_pearson_correlation(predicted_image, true_image, name='pearson_r')
    loss = 1-(tf.math.square(pearson_r)) 
    return loss
***
***
# Create the network
***
tf.global_variables_initializer()
***
# run training
with tf.Session() as sess:
***
```

Comment: Anything is possible, given enough time, money and donuts.

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

If your model has a single output value, you can subclass `tf.keras.losses.Loss`. For example, a trivial custom loss function (which wouldn't be very good in training) implementation:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class LossCustom(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, some_arg):
        super(LossCustom, self).__init__()
        self.param_some_arg = some_arg
    
    def get_config(self):
        config = super(LossCustom, self).get_config()
        config.update({
            "some_arg": self.param_some_arg,
        })
        return config
    
    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        result = y_pred - y_true
        return tf.math.reduce_sum(result)
```

However, **if you have multiple outputs** and want to run them through the same loss function, **you need to artificially combine them into a single value**.

I do this in one of my models with an a dummy layer at the end of my model like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class LayerCheeseMultipleOut(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LayerCheeseMultipleOut, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.stack(inputs, axis=1) # [batch_size, OUTPUTS, .... ]
```

Then, in your custom loss function, unstack again like so:

```py
output_a, output_b = tf.unstack(y_pred, axis=1)
```